# enum type and its linkage in C

Tags: c, enums, linkage

why and how does the following code work?

both a and b have external linkage, but can they be declared by types of no linkage?

if not, why isn't there conflict between MyEnum_t in a.c and MyEnum_t in b.c?

a.h

```
#ifndef _A_H_
#define _A_H_
void print_a_enum();
#endif
```

b.h

```
#ifndef _B_H_
#define _B_H_
void print_b_enum();
#endif
```

a.c

```
#include "a.h"
#include <stdio.h>

enum MyEnum{ ONE = 1, TWO = 2};
typedef enum MyEnum MyEnum_t;

MyEnum_t a = ONE;

void print_a_enum()
{
    printf("%d\n", a);
}
```

b.c

```
#include "b.h"
#include <stdio.h>

enum MyEnum{ ONE = 3, TWO = 4};
typedef enum MyEnum MyEnum_t;

MyEnum_t b = ONE;

void print_b_enum()
{
    printf("%d\n", b);
}
```

main.c

```
#include "a.h"
#include "b.h"

int main()
{
     print_a_enum();
     print_b_enum()
}
```

print out:
   1
   3

gcc version 4.5.0 20100604 [gcc-4_5-branch revision 160292] (SUSE Linux)

Comment: Side node: you can simple write `typedef enum{ ONE = 1, TWO } MyEnum;` in single step

Answer (score 3):

The `enum` type and its values simply don't exist anymore after compilation.  `enum` is a C construct, not anything to do with how your machine actually operates.  You're perfectly allowed to give a particular enumeration type different values in different translation units.  There's nothing the linker is going to be able to do about it later.

If you want to ensure that your `enum` type is consistent, you should probably put a single definition of it in a common header included by all translation units.

Editorial note: Don't use identifiers with leading underscores.  They're reserved by the implementation.